# Wait function with promise to end

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a collection from firebase and later call a function that will insert data. Problem is that the insert data is been called before the compare function ends...

This is the guide that I am following:

1 - Get the game inputs and create an array with the videos to recommend

2 - Get the already recommended videos from user

3 - Compare the videos with the array to exclude duplicates.

4 - Proceed to next function to insert the array to firebase.

Problem is that for step 4 I need step 3 to be completed. But that's not happening. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

```
export const generateRecommendationsFromGame = (participantID) => {
  var newRec = [];
  let userRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(participantID);


  //1 Game inputs
  return firebase.firestore().collection("inputGame").where("user", "==", userRef).onSnapshot({}, function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      let consagua = doc.data().consagua;
      let enfart = doc.data().enfartamento;
      let mastig = doc.data().mastigacao;
      let mexdorm = doc.data().mexerdormir;
      let emoc = doc.data().emocoes;

      //13
      //V2.3.2
      if (Number(consagua) >= 3) {
        newRec.push('V2.3.2');
      }
      //15
      //V3.1
      if (Number(enfart) >= 25) {
        newRec.push('V3.1');
      }
      //16
      //V3.2
      if (Number(mastig) >= 40) {
        newRec.push('V3.2');
      }
      //17
      //V3.3
      //18
      //V3.4
      if (Number(mexdorm) >= 3) {
        newRec.push('V3.3');
        newRec.push('V3.4');
      }
      //19
      //V3.5
      if (Number(emoc) >= 2) {
        newRec.push('V3.5');
      }


      //2 - User Videos
      return firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").where("user", "==", userRef).get().then(result2 => {
        result2.forEach(doc2 => {

          //3 - Get video ref to compate to Array
          var videoFef = doc2.data().video.id;
          firebase.firestore().collection("videos").doc(videoFef).get().then(
            function(doc2) {
              if (doc2.exists) {
                var sequence = doc2.data().sequenceNumberID;
                for (var i = 0; i < newRec.length; i++) {
                  if (String(sequence) == String(newRec[i])) {
                    var index = newRec.indexOf(newRec[i]);
                    if (index > -1) {
                      newRec.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                  }
                }
              } else alert("Não existe doc videos");
            }
          )
        });
      }).then(() => {
         insertData(newRec);
      })
    });
  })
};
```

Then, after the video is compared and the duplicated excluded, I want to call a functions to insert the videos on Firebase.

```
export const insertData= (arr) => {   
  var newRec = arr.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < newRec.length; i++) {
    var ref = newRec[i];
    firebase.firestore().collection("videos").where("sequenceNumberID", "==", ref.toString()).onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").add({
          seen: false,
          user: firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(participantID),
          video: firebase.firestore().collection('videos').doc(doc.id)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          alert(error);
        })
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `insertData` after the first snippet is finished?

Comment: Was calling it right after the step 3 ends like this. .then(() => {
                    insertData(newRec);
                })

Comment: `right after the step 3 ends` Where specifically in the code, I don't see it?

Comment: edited. I removed from code because it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an asynchronous query for each `doc2` and then continue on to `insertData` after all queries are done. The right tool for this is `Promise.all`, which takes an array of promises and resolves once all promises in the array are resolved. So, map each `doc2` to a Promise.

In addition to `Promise.all`, use `async`/`await` to greatly reduce your indentation hell.

Note that you're shadowing (duplicating) the `doc2` variable inside the `forEach`, which can easily cause confusion - better to call it some other name (eg `doc3`):

Make the `querySnapshot.forEach` async:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
```

and then:

```
//2 - User Videos
const result2 = await firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").where("user", "==", userRef).get();
await Promise.all(result2.map(async (doc2) => {
  //3 - Get video ref to compate to Array
  const videoFef = doc2.data().video.id;
  const doc3 = await firebase.firestore().collection("videos").doc(videoFef).get();
  if (!doc3.exists) {
    alert("Não existe doc videos");
    return;
  }
  var sequence = doc3.data().sequenceNumberID;
  for (var i = 0; i < newRec.length; i++) {
    if (String(sequence) !== String(newRec[i])) return;
    var index = newRec.indexOf(newRec[i]);
    if (index > -1) newRec.splice(index, 1);
  }
}));
// end of Promise.all
insertData(newRec);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. After I call the Promise.all it stops. I put on an alert where it says //3 and doesn't pop up. Any suggestion?

Comment: Any console errors? Does `result2` get properly defined as an array?

Comment: the typeof alert shows it is an object. Should it be object or array?

Comment: Arrays *are* objects. If `result2` isn't an array, it should have errored when `map` was called. You can check to see if something is an array with `Array.isArray`, but the console should be enough.

Comment: I am getting this on the console. TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'result2.map')

Comment: Well, if you copied my code exactly, it's doing exactly the same thing to retrieve `result2` as your original `return firebase.firestore().... .then(` line; if `get` returns a thennable that resolves to a variable we call `results2`.

Comment: The result2 has 6 documents inside it. Should I use foreach after promise all? Or the promise all run all the documents?

Comment: await result2.forEach(async doc => {}  this runs over the documents but still calls the add data method before the result2 ends. This makes no sense to me anymore.

Comment: Wait, so you *can* iterate over `result2` with `forEach`? Why can't you `.map` it? You can't `await` a `forEach` call, `forEach` is always synchronous; you should await the `Promise.all` over a `map`ping of the objects to an array of promises.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to solve this.

```
        var reads = [];

        await firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").where("user", "==", userRef).onSnapshot({}, function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(async doc => {
                reads.push(doc);
            })
            return Promise.all(reads.map(async (doc1) => {
                //3 - Get video ref to compate to Array
                const videoFef = doc1.data().video.id;
                const doc3 = await firebase.firestore().collection("videos").doc(videoFef).get();
                if (!doc3.exists) {
                    alert("Não exisste doc videos");
                    return;
                }

                var sequence = doc3.data().sequenceNumberID;
                for (var i = 0; i < newRec.length; i++) {
                    if (String(sequence) == String(newRec[i])) {
                        var index = newRec.indexOf(newRec[i]);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            newRec.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })).then(function() {
                insertData(newRec, participantID);
            });
        });
```

Thanks CertainPerformance for the help.